# how to change csvparsersettings of junit parameterized tests using @csvsource

Tags: java, junit5, parameterized-tests

Given a simple test-method, annotated as `@ParameterizedTest`, employing input via Annotation `@CsvSource` (e.g.`@CsvSource({ "@", "*", "#", "?", "-", "$", "!", "0" }`). When running said test, the test interrupts as soon as `"#"` is supposed to be tested. When reading through the stacktrace/exception, I found the following:

```
org.junit.jupiter.params.shadow.com.univocity.parsers.common.TextParsingException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - Unable to skip 1 lines from line 2. End of input reached
  Parser Configuration: CsvParserSettings:
    ...
    CsvFormat:
      Comment character=# 
      Field delimiter=,
      Line separator (normalized)=\n
      Line separator sequence=\r\n
      Quote character='
      Quote escape character='
      Quote escape escape character=null
```

I guess the problem is in the last block (`Comment character=#`): The specific parameter is being read as comment. How do I change this setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the comment character.

You *could* wrap the `#` in single quotes like this:

`@CsvSource({ "@", "*", "'#'", "?", "-", "$", "!", "0" })`

But you actually shouldn't be using `@CsvSource` for single strings anyway.

Instead, simply use the following:

`@ValueSource(strings = { "@", "*", "#", "?", "-", "$", "!", "0" })`

Comment: Thank you! Tried many ways of escaping the `#`, surprised that it were single quotes. This also works for an input beginning with `#`, and tailed with multiple subsequent characters, e.g. `#abc` (which also leads to the interruption of the testcase, for anyone that's interested).

Do you know why this works, by chance?

Comment: If you wrap `#` in single quotes, the first character is `'` instead of `#`. So the text is then no longer interpreted as a comment.